# codeigniter error in foreach passing variable and query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to populate a dropdown form with an array of events from a database table.

I am getting all kinds of errors:

undefined $user_events

etc.

I know it is the way I am passing the array from the controller I think.

Model:

```
public function dropdown_add_event($id, $Id) 
    {

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM table_eventcards
            WHERE table_eventcards.id = ?
            AND table_eventcards.Id = ?";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id, $Id));
    return $query->result_array();

    }
```

Controller:

```
$this->data['user_events'] = $this->model_location->dropdown_add_event(); // Retrieve an array of     user events
```

View:

```
<?php 
                $user_events = '';
                if($user_events){
                foreach($user_events as $events): {
                ?>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Add Event To Location</h3>
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div id="myselect" class="col-md-12">
                        <p></p>

                      <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-3">


                        <?php
                        $attributes = 'input type="hidden" name="myselect" value="events[]"';
                         echo form_dropdown('myselect', $events, '',$attributes);    
                        ?> 
                      <button id="grab1" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                      <hr/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <?php 
              }
              endforeach;

              }
              ?>
```

Updated:

$Id is already defined a few lines above:

```
$data['Id'] = $this->session->userdata['logged_data']['member_id'];
```

Comment: Shouldn't you pass some arguments here `$this->model_location->dropdown_add_event();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, it seems you forgot to gave out parameters:

```
$this->data['user_events'] = $this->model_location->dropdown_add_event();
                                                                 //   ^^ $id, $fkUserId
```

No parameters are passed/found `dropdown_add_event();`

Just pass the appropriate variables that you have on your controller:

```
$fkUserId = $data['fkUserId'];
$this->data['user_events'] = $this->model_location->dropdown_add_event($id, $fkUserId);
$this->load->view('view_name', $this->data);
```

Comment: whoops simple mistake, thanks, but now it is saying undefined variable $id and undefined variable $fkUserId. Where do I define them?

Comment: @Bobby what do you mean? isn't it (those variables) are found in your controller?

Comment: at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @Bobby oh okay, and i'm assuming you already got your `$id` right? check my revision

Comment: maybe it is because I am tired but I think I am grabbing the id of the TACTIFY_eventcards.id  that is in the query. I am not sure how I should set the $id as I do not see one. I am working on someone else's code.

Comment: @Bobby well i think this is outside the scope now since i'm not really working on your project, but just the thing is, its just missing that `$id` and `$fkUserId` (which is found now), but the way i see it, thats the only thing thats preventing that function not to work, just provide that two arguments/parameters and should work just fine then.